# User Profile Pictures from Sharepoint 2010 - C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

What are the ways by which we can download all profile pictures of all users from sharepoint 2010.

I want to develop a code which can be run from a remote machine.

Does this can be done using Sharepoint User Profile Service ?

I intend to get the images for all users from share point and save them in different database via C#.

Thanks !!

Comment: I have tried to use Sharepoint API, but the code can't be run on a remote machine. The api can be used only on machine which has sharepoint server on it. Also i tried to use Sharepoint webservices. But i don't think you can get the profile picture of all the users of sharepoint by using sharepoint web service.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple different approaches:

http://spsatheesh.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/download-all-the-profile-pictures-through-powershell-using-web-service/